# Documenting class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, self-documenting

Following sample is taken from "Dive into python" book.

```
class MP3FileInfo(FileInfo):
    "store ID3v1.0 MP3 tags"
    tagDataMap = ...
```

This sample shows documenting the MP3FileInfo, but how can I add help to MP3FileInfo. tagDataMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it into a property method.

Comment: I wonder about this, since then you have to create explicit getter, setter and deleter (I want all three), only to have it behave normally. Is there a way to set default methods for these that simply wrap a class attribute?

Answer (score 4):

The [PEP 224](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/) on attribute docstrings was rejected (long time ago), so this is a problem for me as well, sometimes I don't know to choose a class attribute or an instance property -- the second can have a docstring.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
class MP3FileInfo(FileInfo):
    """Store ID3v1.0 MP3 tags."""

    @property 
    def tagDataMap(self):
        """This function computes map of tags.

        The amount of work necessary to compute is quite large, therefore
        we memoize the result.

        """
        ...
```

Note though you really shouldn't make a separate docstring if the attribute has only a one-line description. Instead, use

```
class MP3FileInfo(FileInfo):
    """Store ID3v1.0 MP3 tags.

    Here are the attributes:
        tagDataMap -- contains a map of tags

    """

    tagDataMap = ...
```

Comment: in my case attribute has public visibility - that is why help(tagDataMap) is what I want to get